# 3DEXPERIENCE 2021X How do you change an Enterprise Item Number (EIN) programmatically?

Tags: vba, catia

I just started programming with 3DEXPERIENCE, but I'm familiar with programming macros for CATIA V5. I'm trying to change the **Enterprise Item Number (EIN)** using VBA.

So far, I've found that some attributes like the product title can be changed using

```
VPMOccurence_object.InstanceOccurrenceOf.ReferenceInstanceOf.SetAttributeValue "V_Name", "new title"
```

And that the product instance name can be modified with

```
VPMOccurence_object.InstanceOccurrenceOf.SetAttributeValue "PLM_ExternalID", "new instance name"
```

I'm unsure if the EIN can be changed with the .SetAttributeValue method? Maybe a different input string can be used (e.g., "V_ein" instead of "V_Name")? I've tried the names that I thought are intuitive with that method like "V_ein" and "V_enterprise_item_number". I've found this site that has some of the input strings https://catiahelp.azurewebsites.net/English/CAADocPLMPackage/PLMClass_PLMTaskAction.htm

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in this post:
http://www.coe.org/p/fo/et/thread=31339

Looks like you can read EIN in VBA with:

```
VPMReference.GetAttributeValue("V_PartNumber")
```

However, writing to an EIN with:

```
VPMReference.SetAttributeValue "V_PartNumber", "New EIN"
```

Gives a permission denied error

It sounds like EINs can be written with Enterprise Knowlege Language (EKL). I don't know how to use EKL, but syntax can be found from the Language Browser. The EKL function to write to EINs is:

```
SetEnterpriseItemNumber("new EIN")
```